# wildcard selection using D3

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I have the following structure in my DOM

\    < circle class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" \ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" 
\      radius="300" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobid_29126" ipaddress="1.1.1.2" \

I need to select all circles having their `ipaddress` starting with "1.1" or their `jobid` matching a certain pattern, such as "jobid_29"

How can this be achieved using D3.js?

On the back of the positive answers I have received I would like an additional feature added to my circles.

I need to add animation to my circles when a pattern selection is met. something similar to this 
https://codepen.io/riccardoscalco/pen/GZzZRz

For example  when a search criteria is entered into an input box say "1.1"  I need to apply animation to all circles having their Ipaddress starting with the input value.

This is what I have tried so far without success.

html:
`<label id="InteractiveSearch" style="font-weight:bold"> Interactive Seach : 
   </label>
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Ipaddress or Space ID...">`

script:
`$("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {            d3.selectAll("circle[ipaddress^='" + $(this).val() +`"'").attr("class","svg-triangle pulse")    });`

css:

`.pulse {`
    fill: white;
`fill-opacity: 0;`
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
`animation-duration: 2s;`
    animation-name: pulse;
`animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}`

`@keyframes pulse {`
    from {
`stroke-width: 3px;`
       stroke-opacity: 1;
`transform: scale(0.3);`
   }

`to {`
        stroke-width: 0;
`stroke-opacity: 0;`
        transform: scale(2);
`}
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For selecting all the circles whose `ipaddress` start with `1.1`, use the *"starts with"* [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> **[attr^=value]**
>
> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

Here is a basic demo using your structure. There are four circles, then I'm selecting the ones whose `ipaddress` start with `1.1` (the first and second ones) and painting them green:

```js
d3.selectAll("circle[ipaddress^='1.1']").style("fill", "lime")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobid_29126" ipaddress="1.1.1.2"></circle>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobid_29126" ipaddress="1.1.1.2"></circle>
  <circle cx="150" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobid_29126" ipaddress="3.1.1.2"></circle>
  <circle cx="200" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobid_29126" ipaddress="4.1.1.2"></circle>
</svg>
```

For selecting all the circles whose `jobid` contains a pattern, use:

> **[attr*=value]**
>
> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

Here is the demo, this time the circles containing the desired `jobid` are the second and the fourth ones:

```js
d3.selectAll("circle[id*='jobid_29']").style("fill", "lime")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobclass_29126" ipaddress="1.1.1.2"></circle>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="foojobid_29126" ipaddress="1.1.1.2"></circle>
  <circle cx="150" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobid_59126" ipaddress="3.1.1.2"></circle>
  <circle cx="200" cy="100" class="svg-triangle" xcoordinates="37618.0859375" ycoordinates="-4401.990234375" r="20" jobid="F5-0301" id="jobid_29126" ipaddress="4.1.1.2"></circle>
</svg>
```

---

PS: there is no attribute `radius` for SVG circles, it is `r` instead.